# Finding objects by class or id in HTML parser

Tags: f#, f#-data

There is a [nice library](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/HtmlParser.html) for parsing HTML files in F#. I can easily get all `<a>` objects:

```
let links = results.Descendants ["a"]
```

But what about searching for objects with specific classes or id? Does this library provide such functionality?

Unfortunately, documentation of this library is quite bad, I don't really know what exactly I can do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a work-in-progress pull request [adding CSS selectors to F# Data](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/pull/886). If you can help us by testing it and reviewing it, that would be great!

In the meantime, you can use standard F# collection processing functions - for example, to find `<a>` elements with `class="fl"`, you can write:

```
results.Descendants ["a"]
|> Seq.filter (fun a -> 
    a.TryGetAttribute("class")
    |> Option.map (fun cls -> cls.Value()) = Some "fl")
|> Seq.iter (fun l -> 
    printfn "%s" (l.InnerText()))
```